# Using of ALL/ANY/NONE in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to understand NSPredicate and it's syntax, when we are using ALL/ANY etc

My class Person:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* surname;
@property NSUInteger age;
@property NSUInteger weight;
@property NSUInteger height;
```

And I use it for predicates like this:

```
NSArray* persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:personOne, personTwo, personThree, personFour, nil];
```

My predicate:

```
NSPredicate* predicateEight = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.age > %@", @55]; 
filteredArray = [persons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateEight];
NSLog(@"Age > 55 %@", filteredArray);
```

And I've received a mistake:

> The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an
>   NSArray or an NSSet

How I need to change my code? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;)

ALL/ANY used for NSArray or NSSet. In your case ANY used for instance of Person.

Example of use ANY:

```
NSPredicate* predicateEight = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.age > %@", @55];
BOOL result = [predicateEight evaluateWithObject:persons];
```

If you have Array of persons (Array of Arrays):

```
NSArray* group1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:personOne, personTwo, personThree, nil];
NSArray* group2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:personFour, personFive, personSix, nil];
NSArray* group3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:personSeven, personEight, personNine, nil];

NSArray* groups = [NSArray group1, group2, group3, nil];

NSPredicate* predicateEight = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.age > %@", @55];

NSArray* filteredArray = [groups filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateEight];
```

Comment: Вадим, Вы бяка :) 
Но по теме, согласен ))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

It should like this :

```
NSPredicate* predicateEight = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.age > %d", 55];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's classic using.
And if I'd like to use exactly ALL/ANY (for understanding where it's possible to use it), how it will looks like? Maybe I need to add some structure?